# How do I copy html, css, Javascript code from email

Tags: html

I am trying to copy code from an email into a a Web page file.   I would like the file to have functionality.
I tried copying it directly into a new Sublime file but the colors did not appear as if I had typed it in.  When I right clicked background, no open in browser option appeared.  I am experimenting with code snippets in blogs and having problems pasting code with functionality in tact.  Is this an extension omission ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at the email source? [How to find Source for HTML Email](https://superuser.com/questions/12255/how-to-find-source-for-html-email) (Emails don't support JavaScript BTW.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime will copy plain text, a wysiwyg html editor will copy the markup. If you want to get the markup, do 'show original' (gmail) or whatever your client has as an equivalent. The original will have the markup and can be copied into Sublime. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to see if I can copy.from the body of the Gmail in a different way.

Comment: If I make a new folder and in that right click to make a new file, the only option close to what I am looking for is .txt file.  I can open in chrome but cannot edit from view source code.  How can I edit the code ?  Thanks...not well versed in file management

Comment: I discovered that my sublime 2 was corrupted.  Things are working out much better with sublime 3.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to copy the rich text from the email and paste it first into a tool like [Convert text to HTML](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/text-to-html/) and then copy and paste the HTML from there.

I've developed [my own applet for this](https://jsfiddle.net/1j01/rz5h4g1t/), which speeds up the process slightly by automatically focusing the input and then the output. I've included the applet here as a code snippet which you can run.

Note that you may want to clean up the HTML depending on how you want to use it, for example with [DirtyMarkup](https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/). One tool that combines these functions by letting you paste rich text as input is [HTML Cleaner](https://html-cleaner.com/).

```js
const pasteBox = document.getElementById("paste-box");
const htmlOutput = document.getElementById("html-output");
pasteBox.onblur =
pasteBox.onpaste = ()=> {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        const html = pasteBox.innerHTML;
        htmlOutput.value = html;
        htmlOutput.focus();
        htmlOutput.select();
    });
};
pasteBox.focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
```

```css
#paste-box,
#html-output,
#markdown-output {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#paste-box {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
}
#html-output {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="paste-box" contentEditable="true" tabIndex="-1">
  Paste rich text here!
</div>
<textarea id="html-output"></textarea>
```